# Realtime access to iPhone's camera images

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I'm trying to read an (average) RGB-value of the center pixel(s) of the iPhone camera. This should almost happen in realtime. Therefore I open a UIImagePickerController, use a timer to take a picture every x seconds. Processing the picture is made in a separate thread such that it does not block the app while computing the RGB-value. I tried several ways to access the RGB/pixel values of the taken image, but all have the problem that they are too slow and cause the camera view to lag.
I tried the following:

```
- (UIColor *)getAverageColorOfImage:(UIImage*)image {
int pixelCount = kDetectorSize * kDetectorSize;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * kDetectorSize;
NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
unsigned char *rawData = malloc(pixelCount * bytesPerPixel);
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, kDetectorSize, kDetectorSize, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationNone);

NSLog(@"Drawing image");
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, kDetectorSize, kDetectorSize), [image CGImage]);
NSLog(@"Image drawn");

CGContextRelease(context);

// rawData contains the image data in the RGBA8888 pixel format. Alpha values are ignored
int byteIndex = 0;
CGFloat red = 0.0;
CGFloat green = 0.0;
CGFloat blue = 0.0;

for (int i = 0 ; i <  pixelCount; ++i) {
    red   += rawData[byteIndex];
    green += rawData[byteIndex + 1];
    blue  += rawData[byteIndex + 2];
    byteIndex += bytesPerPixel;
}

free(rawData);

return [UIColor colorWithRed:red/pixelCount/255.0 green:green/pixelCount/255.0 blue:blue/pixelCount/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
```

kDetectorSize is set to 6 such that the processed image has a size of 6x6 pixels. The one of the image-parameter also has been cropped to 6x6 pixels before. The slow part is CGContextDrawImage which takes about 500-600ms on my iPhone 4. I tried some alternatives for that line:

```
UIGraphicsPushContext(context); 
[image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)];
UIGraphicsPopContext();
```

or

```
UIGraphicsPushContext(context); 
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, kDetectorSize, kDetectorSize)];
UIGraphicsPopContext();
```

Both approaches are as slow as the one above. The image size does not have a significant influence (I'd say it has no influence).
Does anyone know a faster way to access the RGB value?

It would be ok, too, if the thread would not cause the camera view to lag. I call my thread like that:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(pickColorFromImage:) toTarget:self withObject:image]; 
}

- (void)pickColorFromImage:(UIImage *)image {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];   
    [NSThread setThreadPriority:0.0];

    [...cropping the image...]
UIColor *averageColor = [self getAverageColorOfImage:croppedImage];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(applyPickedColor:) withObject:averageColor waitUntilDone:NO];  

    [pool release];
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're approaching this in the wrong way - Apple offer a class to do exactly what you want without messing around with timers and UIImagePickers. `AVCaptureSession` and related classes give you realtime access to raw pixel data from the camera(s).

For more information refer to the documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009521